# Add stuff with prompts

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a thing that adds two numbers with `prompt()`s and when it returns the sum it shows the numbers in the wrong way. For instance, I would put 5 for the first number and 2 for the second number and it returns 52. Here's the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="h2">gonna be something</h2>
    <button onclick="math()">might do something</button>
    <script>
        function math() {
        var text = document.getElementById("h2")
        var question1 = prompt("enter a number","here")
        var question2 = prompt("enter a second number","here")
        text.innerHTML = 
        question1 += question2
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to parse the values as int.

Comment: `text.innerHTML = 
        question1 += question2` that is just strange syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the `prompt` return to int in order to do the calculation. If you don't do it, the values will be concatenated instead of added.

```
var question1 = parseInt(prompt("enter a number","here"))
var question2 = parseInt(prompt("enter a second number","here"))
```

You can also test if the input was really a number before the conversion:

```
var question1 = prompt("enter a number","here")
var question2 = prompt("enter a second number","here")

if (!isNaN(question1) && !isNaN(question2)){
  question1 = parseInt(question1)
  question2 = parseInt(question2)
}
```